# Using the given table, what are the values of width and height that give the areas of square?

Tags: area

The table shows the calculated rectangle areas for the given width and height values.

Using the given table, what are the values of width and height that give the areas of square?

[image: table]

please help? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: width=height=$a$ in a square.
and $a^2= area$ . 
can't give a better to your question

Comment: ok!!!! now I get it! :D I finally knew the answer, thank you so much for the Law! <3